# Removing "that of" from "A more important subject than that of getting indoors"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, ellipsis, comparison

This sentence is from ["The Return of the Native Book II, Chapter 6"](https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/returnofnative/full-text/book-ii-chapter-6/)

> A more important subject than that of getting indoors now engrossed her

Can I delete "that of", as in below?

> A more important subject than getting indoors now engrossed her

Both sound okay to me. What is the difference between the sentences?

Comment: In the case of a simple sentence like the one you have quoted, it will work without the "that of". But in the case of a long and complicated excursion into detail about something, then "that of" would aid clarification.